# asp.net mvc ajax driving me mad

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

how come when I send ajax request like this everything works

```
   $(".btnDeleteSong").click(function () {

    var songId = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/DeleteSong/",
        data: { id: songId },
        success: ShowMsg("Song deleted successfully"),
        error:  ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be deleted, please try again"),
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

But when I add the anonymous function to the success It always showes me the error message although the song is still deleted

```
 $(".btnDeleteSong").click(function () {

    var songId = $(this).attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/DeleteSong/",
        data: { id: songId },
        success: function () { ShowMsg("Song deleted successfully"); },
        error: function () {
            ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be deleted, please try again");
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

what if i wanted few things on success of the ajax call, I need to be able to use the anonymous function and I know that's how it should be done, but what am I doing wrong?
I want the success message to show not the error one.

```
function ShowMsg(parameter) { 
      $("#msg").find("span").replaceWith(parameter); 
      $("#msg").css("display", "inline"); 
      $("#msg").fadeOut(2000); 
      return false; 
}
```

Comment: It is odd that the first block works, what is ShowMsg? You should examine the Ajax request with fiddler and see what it's status actually is.

Comment: function ShowMsg(parameter) {

    $("#msg").find("span").replaceWith(parameter);
    $("#msg").css("display", "inline");
    $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);
    return false;
}

Comment: The first block is actually executing ShowMsg right away, not waiting for a result. I see nothing wrong with the second block, if the error callback is executed it must have something to do with the response. Is it actually returning Json?

Comment: ok so it's got to be the line with json, because my action is not returning any json

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your action is returning Json data.

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Your action method should surely return Json data. I have the similar code see if that helps.

```
 public ActionResult GetAllByFilter(Student student)
    {
        return Json(new { data = this.RenderPartialViewToString("PartialStudentList", _studentViewModel.GetBySearchFilter(student).ToList()) });
    }


 $("#btnSearch").live('click',function () {

        var student = {
            Name: $("#txtSearchByName").val(),
            CourseID: $("#txtSearchByCourseID").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
                    url: '/StudentRep/GetAllByFilter',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(student),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
                        RefreshPartialView(result.data);
                    }
                , error: function() { alert('some error occured!!'); }
                });

    });
```

Above code is used to reload a partial view. in your case it should be straight forward.

Thanks,
Praveen